# Mint Linux can't find allocated ssd disk sapce

Tags: installation, linux-mint, multiboot

My laptop DELL PRECISION 3530 has 1 TB SSD. First I installed Windows 10 in 300 GB. and left the rest unallocated. I planned to install Mint Linux for the rest of the space. When I boot Mint Linux by a bootable USB and try to install it, it doesn't find unallocated space. What is wrong how to fix it? Please suggest me!

Comment: You can try to use gparted and have a look at the partition table. But this question is offtopic and maybe better suited for superuser :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual issue. It is mainly BIOS setup for the latest model laptops comes with UEFI and secure boot options. I had to follow the following options:

1. select UEFI enable it
2. Secure boot disable it.
3. QuickBoot/FastBoot disable it.
4. Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT) disable it.
5. SATA has multiple options. RAIDR, AHCI, etc. Select AHCI mode.

Then boot the Linux infestation by DVD or USB. Well, the latest laptop comes without any CD/DVD ROM.

Now you should see the whole SSD. To verify it just lunch GParted